# Finding points on a tangent line of a parametric equation that are parallel to another parametric equation

Tags: parametric

So I got the tangent line of the first equation to be 12t/(3t^2+4) and I changed the second parametric equation to the cartesian form and got y= -(12/7x+5) with 12/7 as my slope. I equated 12t/(3t^2+4)= 12/7 and solve for t using the quadratic formula. I got the values -1 and -4/3 but they are incorrect. So, I'm confused where I went wrong. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $y = (-12/7)x - 5$, the slope of the second line should be -12/7 instead.

Also, the solutions to $\frac{12t}{3t^2+4} = \frac{12}{7}$ are $1, \frac{4}{3}$ and $-1, -\frac{4}{3}$ are instead the solutions to $\frac{12t}{3t^2+4} = -\frac{12}{7}$

For the points $(y(t), x(t))$ of the solution, you should plug in $t = -1, -4/3$ into your equation for $x,y$.

Otherwise , your general approach is fine.

Comment: Hey, I thought the equation of a line was in the form y=mx+b, so wouldn't the equation be y= -(12/7x +5) where the slope is 12/7? And even if the slope is -12/7, the values of -1 and -4/3 for the x value of the points are still incorrect :/ so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: $y = -(mx+b)$ is equivalent to $y = -mx -b$, so the slope is negative.  See my edited answer w.r.t. getting $x$-values.

Comment: :/ I still get the values of -1 and -4/3 with the slope of -12/7?

Comment: remember that you have solved for $t$ values, and need to get $x$- and $y$-values for your answer

Comment: ohhhhh damn you are right. :) thanks